# How do I randomly join the users input to strings stored in an array using random.choice

Tags: python, loops, validation, random, pseudocode

I need to write a program that will automatically generate unique usernames for students. The usernames have to be six characters long. The program should generate and display a list of student usernames.
The program will ask how many usernames are to be generated. For each username, the first three letters of the student’s first name will be entered and then combined with a random ending from the list below:
Ing, end, axe, gex, goh
For a student with the first name David, the technician would enter Dav. The program will generate the username by RANDOMLY joining Dav to one of the endings. For example – Daving.

This is all I have so far, **I would really appreciate it if anyone knows how to use random.choice to randomly combine the students first 3 letters of their name to the endings that are stored in the array. Thank you!**

my code so far:

```
#Initialising the variables
usernames=0
usernameEndings=["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
studentsName=""
#Getting inputs
usernames=int(input("How many ``usernames are to be generated?"))
#proccess
for counter in range(0,usernames):
    studentsName = str(input("Please enter the first three letters of students name."))
        while len(str(studentsName)) <3 or len(str(studentsName)) >3:
        studentsName= str(input("ERROR, please re-enter the first three letters of students name."))
```

Comment: "Please help me do the rest:" Is not a useful request.  Can you find exactly what you need to do and don't know how? Are there issues in what you have so far? What are they?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've gotten a good deal of the way already. For the next step, you'll want to consider using [random](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) for the choice, and you'll need some kind of data structure to store the values. Good luck!

Comment: @Hoog Hi, thanks for your feedback! The issue I'm having is that I'm not sure how to randomly concatenate the endings from the array and the first three letters of the students name together to give an output such as "Daving"

Comment: @Josh Friedlander   Hi, thanks fro you feedback. I have added a comment above to show the issue I am having. I was going to use an array to store the first three letters of the entered students names but I want very sure how I would do that

Comment: if student's name was `Alice`, then `import random` followed by `'Ali' + random.choice(usernameEndings)` points you in the right direction...

Comment: @Josh Friedlander   the student or lecturer would be entering the name of the student so I would not be able to store "Ali" separately without a data structure such as an array so this is the main trouble I'm having. thank you for your help with the random part, hopefully that will help me.but I'm very unsure of how I would do the array as the separate names will be input into the program, not pre stored

Answer (score 0):

I've made some minor style tweaks in your code, corrected an indentation error, and added the line you were missing. If there's no need to store the usernames, the program can simply print out each username in turn:

```
import random

#Initialising the variables 
usernames = 0
usernameEndings = ["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
studentsName = ""
#Getting inputs
usernames=int(input("How many usernames are to be generated?"))
#process
for counter in range(0,usernames):
    studentsName = str(input("Please enter the first three letters of students name."))
    while len(str(studentsName)) != 3:
        studentsName = str(input("ERROR, please re-enter the first three letters of students name."))
    print('Your username is {}'.format(studentsName[:3] + random.choice(usernameEndings)))
```

Output:

```
How many usernames are to be generated?2
Please enter the first three letters of students name.ali
Your username is aligoh
Please enter the first three letters of students name.bob
Your username is bobaxe
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate the help. That has helped a lot. thank you.

Comment: I am so sorry to keep bothering you. is there a way of instead of generating the random username, to instead generate a random number assigned to each ending that is stored. for example: if the first random number was generated, add the first stored ending to the end of the first three letters of the students name and if the second random number was generated, add the second stored ending to the end of the first three letters of students name etc.

Comment: Yes, just use a dictionary to store `usernameEndings` where the keys are numbers, then generate a random number from the dictionary keys and concatenate its value

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for everybodies help I really appreciate it. it helped me finish my project. here is the code I put together.

```
#Initialising the variables
usernames=0
usernameEndings=["ing", "end", "axe", "gex", "goh"]
studentsName=""

#Getting inputs
usernames=int(input("How many usernames are to be generated?"))

#proccess
for counter in range(0,usernames):
    studentsName = str(input("Please enter the first three letters of students name."))
    while len(str(studentsName)) != 3:     
        studentsName= str(input("ERROR, please re-enter the first three letters of  students name."))
    import random
    print((str(studentsName))+random.choice(usernameEndings))

#end of program
```